# Generate random number with n digits and avoid using 0 as first digit?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to write a function that takes a number `n` and return a randomly generated number having exactly `n` digits (except starting with 0). e.g. if `n` is 2 then function can randomly return a number in range 10-99 but 07,02 etc. are not valid two digit number.

Comment: _How to avoid using 0 as first digit?.._ Seems you already have  implemented the rest of the requirement - Where is that code?

Comment: You basically answered your own question: *"if n is 2 then function can randomly return a number __in range 10-99__"* - [`random.randint(10, 99)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint)...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function that gets as input the number of digits `ndigits`, and returns a random number with `ndigits` digits. I use powers of 10 to get the range of numbers with `ndigits` digits.

```py
import random

...

def random_ndigits(ndigits):
    min_num = 10 ** (ndigits - 1)
    max_num = (10 ** ndigits) - 1

    if ndigits == 1:
        min_num = 0

    return random.randint(min_num, max_num)
```